# Divs set with vw and transition values not scaling smoothly. Any fix?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Here's [my example](https://jsfiddle.net/0r73kosq/) at Jsfiddle

HMTL

```
<div class="right1"></div>  
<div class="right2"></div>  
<div class="right3"></div>  
<div class="right4"></div>  
<div class="right5"></div>

<div class="cube"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .cube-cont {
    width: 20vw;
    height: 20vw;
    background-color: #877c7f;
    margin: 20vh auto;
    position: relative;
}

.right1,
.right2,
.right3,
.right4,
.right5 {
    width: 15vw;
    height: 4vw;
    background-color: #7FC7A6;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 20vw;
    transition: all 1s;
    transform: translateX(-12vw);
}

.right2 {
    top: 4vw;
}

.right3 {
    top: 8vw;
}

.right4 {
    top: 12vw;
}

.right5 {
    top: 16vw;
}

.right1:hover,
.right2:hover,
.right3:hover,
.right4:hover,
.right5:hover {
    transform: 1s;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.cube {
    width: 20vw;
    height: 20vw;
    background-color: #877c7f;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

As you can see, when the window resizes the green divs' scaling is delayed slightly which makes resizing appear messy. The grey cube scales perfectly, so it appears to be the transition values causing it.

Any way to fix this so they scale uniformly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the green divs' scaling is delayed slightly which makes resizing appear messy

That's because in this line here `transition: all 1s;` the `1s` means "Do the transition with a duration of 1 second"

Simply change it to 0 or don't write `1s` at all, but then you don't really need the transition, do you? So you can remove that line altogether.

Comment: I do need the transition, I want it to be smoothly transition not just flicker between the X axis positions. Unless I'm missing something about your suggestion?

Comment: Ok. If you remove the transition, resizing the window makes both the `.cube` element and the `.right#` elements resize instantly, as fast as you resize the window. This, is smooth by itself and does not flicker. If you *really* want to have a transition in there, then you should apply it to the `.cube` and `.cube-cont` elements as well, so that all elements transition with the same rate and so you don't have `.cube` transitioning instantly and the rest of the elements transitioning during `1s` time. Fiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/mkarajohn/0r73kosq/1/**

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome! If my answer helped you and resolved your question consider marking it as an accepted answer :)